# How to combine SURF and Harris points MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction, matlab-cvst

As we know at Matlab, there is function to detect Harris or SURF feature individually. Then I need to combine these two list of features from both the Harris and SURF to make the matching more efficient.

the following is the default procedure that we know

```
points_image_Harris =detectHarrisFeatures(image );
[feature_image_Harris, validpoints_image_Harris] = extractFeatures(image,  points_image_Harris ); 
indexPairs_Harris = matchFeatures(feature_template_Harris,feature_image_Harris);
```

but I want to combine two list of points before make matching: something like this:

```
points_image_Harris =detectHarrisFeatures(image );
points_image_SURF =detectSURFFeatures(image );
Points = points_image_Harris  + points_image_SURF
```

then use the Points list to make feature extraction and them matching.
How to do this? if they are have two different types? cornerPoints and SURFPoints !

I need both features generated from both SURF and Harris, as the following output:

[image]

I don't know if the combination is possible or any idea to get both matching features from both.

**Actually I want to detect these features, then I want to get the location of those pixels from the frames and then calculate difference between both X and Y position.**

**Also I don't Know how to get the features coordinates position from the SURF & Harris matching??**

Comment: If you want to combine the physical locations of the feature points themselves, that's straight forward.  If you want to combine both the `cornerPoints` and `SURFPoints` containers together, you can't do that.  They both describe feature points in completely different ways and so if you want to combine them both, you are placing unlike things together into a single container.  That isn't possible.  Please be more specific in how you want to combine them.  Do you just want the physical points only, or do you want to merge the descriptors as well?

Comment: @rayryeng, Please could you see the question again, I have edited it.

Comment: Is it my understanding that you want to find the most similar feature points between both schemes?  In that case, you don't need to merge them at all.  Also, it's possible to get just the coordinates of the features themselves for both frameworks... however, it's still a bit confusing.  At first you say you want to combine the features.... and at the end of the post, you say you just want to extract out the feature coordinates.  Which one is it?

Comment: I am sorry, I want to edit it again, I want to extract out the feature coordinates for both.

Comment: Ah :) That's easy.  Please give me one moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`detectHarrisFeatures`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectharrisfeatures.html) and [`detectSURFFeatures`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectsurffeatures.html) essentially returns a **structure** where each field contains relevant information about the interest points that are detected in the image.  To give a reproducible example, let's use the `cameraman.tif` image that is part of the image processing toolbox.  Let's also use both feature detection frameworks with the default parameters:

```
>> im = imread('cameraman.tif');
>> harrisPoints = detectHarrisFeatures(im);
>> surfPoints = detectSURFFeatures(im);
```

When we display `harrisPoints`, this is what we get:

```
harrisPoints = 

  184x1 cornerPoints array with properties:

    Location: [184x2 single]
      Metric: [184x1 single]
       Count: 184
```

When we display `surfPoints`, this is what we get:

```
surfPoints = 

  180x1 SURFPoints array with properties:

              Scale: [180x1 single]
    SignOfLaplacian: [180x1 int8]
        Orientation: [180x1 single]
           Location: [180x2 single]
             Metric: [180x1 single]
              Count: 180
```

As such, both `harrisPoints` and `surfPoints` have a field called `Location` which contains the spatial coordinates of the features you want.  This would be a `N x 2` matrix where each row gives you the location of a feature point.  The first column is the `x` or horizontal coordinate and the second column is the `y` or vertical coordinate.  The origin is at the top left corner of the image, and the `y` coordinate is positive when moving downwards.

Therefore, if you want to combine both of the feature points together, access the `Location` field of both objects and concatenate them together into a single matrix:

```
>> Points = [harrisPoints.Location; surfPoints.Location];
```

`Points` should now contain a matrix where each row gives you a feature point.

---

I'd like to make a small note that the Harris corner detector is just an interest point detection algorithm.  All that is given to you are the locations of interesting points in the image. SURF is both a detection and **description** framework, where not only do you get interest points, but you also get a good robust description of each interest point that you can use to perform matching between other interest points in other images.  Therefore, if you wanted to combine both Harris and SURF together, that isn't possible because Harris does not support describing interest points.

Comment: Thank you,
but I didn't get 1- how they match feature depend on location points.
2- what the differences between description and Harris?

Comment: @Hanaa - I'm not sure what Harris matching is being done in MATLAB's CVST, but I suspect that they look at intensity patches that surround a given interest point and find the distance between patches.  For your second question, SURF describes keypoints using a 128-bin histogram describing orientation and scale.  Harris only gives you what the spatial locations of the features are.  SURF not only gives you the spatial locations, but they also give you a 128-bin histogram that **describes** each point on top of the spatial location. The histogram is used for matching feature points instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really a good idea to combine points returned by different detectors before matching. It is better to match descriptors extracted from different kinds of interest points separately, and then combine the matched points. Otherwise you would be comparing apples and oranges.

Think about it this way: Harris detects corners, while SURF detects centers of blobs. A Harris corner and a SURF keypoint are very unlikely to correspond to the same physical point in the world. So it makes more sense to match these points separately.